# Can I get an example of how to connect a lambda function to a domain name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've been wasting about 12 hours going in circles in what seems like this:

[image]

I am trying to just make a simple static landing page in lambda and hook the root of a domain to it.

The landing page works, but api gateway didn't because AWS doesn't seem to set permissions properly by default (["internal server error" with API gateway and lambda on AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67665662/internal-server-error-with-api-gateway-and-lambda-on-aws/67665757#67665757)) but now the gateway link works.

So the next steps were the following:

- add a custom domain name in the api gateway
- add the api mapping in the custom domain name
- in route 53, create a wildcard certificate with *.domain.com and domain.com
- create an A record that points to the api gateway with domain.com
- create a CNAME record that points to the A record

and I get an error 403 with absolutely nothing in the log. I log both 'default' and '$default' stages in the api gateway.

I read https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-403-error-lambda-authorizer/ which is all about looking at what's in the logs...

and I find the doc is both everywhere and nowhere because it's built as chunks of 'do this' and 'do that' without ever painting a whole picture of how each piece is connected to the other, or any graph with the hierarchy of services, etc. Reminds me of code that works only when you follow the example documented and breaks otherwise.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but given the lack of logs and lack of cohesive documentation, I have no idea about the problem.

Not to mention that http doesn't even connect, just https.

Can anyone outline the steps needed to achieve this? essentially: [http|https]://(www).domain.com -> one lambda function

Comment: Why you need to use API Gateway in this case? If I understood correctly you want to have a site where the domain point to Lambda. I'm this case API Gateway is not the best option.

Comment: I thought I needed the gateway in order to attach the custom domain to it. How can it be done without the gateway?

Comment: How are you creating the resources (API Gateway, Lambda function)? Are you in the console, command line, using CloudFormation? In the console, a lot of the magic is taken care of for you.

Comment: I’ve used the UI, which is probably why I see everything so disjointed :) learning the pieces needed and using cloud formation would be the best for me because I could see how everything is connected but right now I’m not so sure about all the parts needed either

Comment: If you are using the console UI I'm a little surprised you are having this issue. Most often the issue is that the permissions for the API Gateway to invoke the function are missing/wrong, but the console should have done that for you. Are you sure you've deployed the API gateway? If this is a REST API you have to deploy it for any changes to be visible. I would make sure you are able to execute the function from the API Gateway URL first, and once that's working move to the custom domain.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth I have the gateway deployed now and I've managed to get https://domain to work, but I can't get http://domain to work and also I've added a cname with www and it doesn't seem to execute the lambda function. Is there a way, once you have something working to export the settings of a group of functionalities in a script like cloudformation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say you "managed to get domain to work, but [you] can't get domain to work."

Comment: oh.. that's SO that changed my text: I managed to get https : // domain to work, but not http : // domain (https only, not http)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use API Gateway for an HTTP request; it only supports HTTPS.

From the [Amazon API Gateway FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/) (emphasis mine):

> Q: Can I create HTTPS endpoints?
> Yes, all of the APIs created with Amazon API Gateway expose HTTPS endpoints only. ***Amazon API Gateway does not support unencrypted (HTTP) endpoints***. By default, Amazon API Gateway assigns an internal domain to the API that automatically uses the Amazon API Gateway certificate. When configuring your APIs to run under a custom domain name, you can provide your own certificate for the domain.

You can use CloudFront to automatically redirect HTTP to HTTPS. [How do I set up API Gateway with my own CloudFront distribution?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudfront-distribution/) provides a pretty simple walkthrough of connecting an API Gateway to CloudFront (you can skip the API Gateway portion and use the one you created). The important thing you'll need to do that is not in that document is to select `Redirect HTTP to HTTPS`.

If you truly need HTTP traffic you're probably going to need to go with an ALB.